# How can a SalesForce/PaymentConnect guest user edit stored records?

Tags: permissions, salesforce, sandbox

So for my site right now, my site user, the PaymentConnect user, and the Linvio user all use guest licenses. As a result, none of them appear to have edit/delete permissions. How can a guest user on the site edit a stored SalesForce record such as a contact, if it is even possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little known secret, you used to be able to work-around the limitation on updating standard objects if you didn't use a bound sObject in your VF page controller to update directly, but instead used a bunch of generic properties to represent sObject fields, and then instantiated a new standard sObject in your controller and set the values (including the Id) to the fields you want to update and called the update.  I'm not sure if Salesforce has subsequently locked this down, but it was working.  Your controller will also have to be WITHOUT SHARING in order for this to work.

Comment: Thanks! An earlier version of the program had gotten it to work with a guest license, so I was puzzled as to how.

Answer (score 0):

Sites users can only have read and create permissions to standard objects (and a few standard objects are even more locked down). However, you can fully control access to any custom objects. To change the permissions for a sites user

1. Click Your Name | Setup | Develop | Sites.
2. Click the name of the site you want to control.
3. Click Public Access Settings to open the Profile page for your site profile.

Source: [sites public access settings](http://na3.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sites_public_access_settings.htm)